# Jquery Datatables adding dynamically added footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

Here is my JQuery DataTable code

```
$(function() {
    var collectionTable = $('#collection-list').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sServerMethod": "GET",
        "fnFooterCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api(),
                data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function(i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
            };

            //Sum all Amount of the retrieved tickets
            var total = 0;
            total = api
                .column(7)
                .data()
                .reduce(function(a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0);
            //Update Footer
            $(api.column(7).footer()).html(
                total.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                    style: 'currency',
                    currency: 'PHP'
                })
            );
        },

        "sAjaxSource": "/report/retrieve/all",
        "fnServerParams": function(aoData) {
            aoData.push({
                "name": "startDate",
                "value": $('#target-from').val()
            });
            aoData.push({
                "name": "endDate",
                "value": $('#target-to').val()
            });
        },
        "columns": [{
            "data": "dateTimeCreated"
        }, {
            "data": "invoiceNumber"
        }, {
            "data": "customerName"
        }, {
            "data": "description",
            "className": "pre"
        }, {
            "data": "targetDate"
        }, {
            "data": "processStatus"
        }, {
            "data": "forCollection"
        }, {
            "data": "amount"
        }],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'

        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "targets": 0,
            "data": "dateTimeCreated",
            "mRender": function(data) {
                return Date.create(data).format('{MM}-{dd}-{yyyy} {hh}:{mm}{TT}');
            }
        }, {
            "targets": 8,
            "className": 'text-center',
            "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
                var view = [
                    [@ {
                        /collection/view /
                    }]
                ] + full.id;
                var edit = [
                    [@ {
                        /collection/edit /
                    }]
                ] + full.id;
                return '<a sec:authorize="hasRole('
                ROLE_COLLECTION_VIEW ')" class="label label-primary" href="' + view + '"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a> ' +
                    '<a sec:authorize="hasRole('
                ROLE_COLLECTION_EDIT ')" class="label label-warning" href="' + edit + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>'
            }
        }, {
            "targets": 4,
            "data": "targetDate",
            "mRender": function(data) {
                return Date.create(data).format('{MM}-{dd}-{yyyy} {hh}:{mm}{TT}');
            }
        }],
    });

    $("#search-collection-btn").click(function() {
        collectionTable.fnDraw();
    });

    $("#customer").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/company/search",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(customer) {
                        return {
                            label: customer.name,
                            value: customer.name
                        }
                    }))
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                $("#customer").val("");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and here's the markup/data I have.

```
<table id="collection-list" class="no-border blue">
    <thead class="no-border">
        <tr>
            <th><strong>Date Created</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Invoice #</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Customer</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Item Description</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Target Date</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Status</strong></th>
            <th><strong>For Collection</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Amount</strong></th>
            <th class="text-center"><strong>Actions</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Total:</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody class="no-border-x no-border-y"></tbody>
</table>
```

However, I've read in the documentation(https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdf) that I can include the footer whenever I generate the pdf.

however, with the given code it does not display the pdf with the footer.

In here, my value of total in the table is automatically computed through my footer callback. how do do I specify that It should include the table footer(which contents are computed through my callback) every time I generate a pdf of the datatable?

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: All of my data are coming from the server side I am not quite sure If I can send those data through jsfiddle

Comment: well you can mock the data on jsfiddle , refer this https://jsfiddle.net/hofo/x7s9c4wL/